# MySQL Difficult Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a difficult query which I may not explain well with words.

The query needs to only return results where all the characters in the code column are in the where clause.

Say I had the following table and wanted to return the code and position where ABC.

Table:

| code | position |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 100 |
| ABCD | 200 |
| ABCDE | 300 |
| CBA | 400 |
| BCA | 500 |
| A | 600 |
| BC | 700 |
| KABC | 800 |
| CABD | 900 |
| CA | 1000 |

Expected Results:

| code | position |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 100 |
| CBA | 400 |
| BCA | 500 |
| A | 600 |
| BC | 700 |
| CA | 1000 |

I have tried many variations of like with both % and _ operator’s. Beginning to think MySQL doesn’t have this functionality. Any ideas? I’m at the end of my rope.

Comment: Have you maybe looked at [regexp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html)? Don't know how it performs, but maybe fits your usecase. Functions do depend on your version of mysql.

Comment: @Sam020. Sorry, tried that too, but perhaps I’m not using it to it’s full potential. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can provide one or two examples of SQL you have tried? Would help other responders as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach to @Barbaros Özhan (which I like a lot) is by using REGEXP, like so:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM test
WHERE `code` REGEXP '[^ABC]' = 0;
```

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/unPxE5Dus6D3RR9XL7W9Zr/1)

This is basically filtering out every [code] which contains any other character than 'ABC'. This is case-sensitive though, but you can add options to the regexp to make it case-insensitive (and many other options).

Check the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: ------------->

Comment: Would there be advantage to one method over the other, REGEXP vs Length Replace?

Comment: One downside to the REGEXP method might be compatibility with other DB systems. Or maybe speed.

Comment: The REGEXP was faster on my few quick tests. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use concurrent `REPLACE()` functions in order to pick the letters `A`,`B`,`C` as been reduced from the values of the `code` column, and then apply `LENGTH()` function such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM t
 WHERE LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(code,'A',''),'B',''),'C',''))=0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd93ade18d34f14265371787a675b73d)</kbd>

Comment: Wow. Does the way you constructed the table with ‘union all’ have any bearing on how this works? Just trying to understand it.